# Set the background color to a cell based on a hex value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I want to set the background color to a cell based on a hex value in another cell. What I have done so far:

```
function setColorHEX(hex) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  cell.setBackground(hex);
}
```

[image]

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to do the same and found this script. It works great, though I did have to highlight all the existing cells and copy/paste them back in to get it to work. Credit: https://gist.github.com/wjmazza/131c050b88bb2a595d6049707693ec13

[image]

```
/*

This script is meant to be used with a Google Sheets spreadsheet. When you edit a cell containing a
valid CSS hexadecimal colour code (like #000 or #000000), the background colour will be changed to
that colour and the font colour will be changed to the inverse colour for readability.

To use this script in a Google Sheets spreadsheet:
1. go to Tools » Script Editor » Spreadsheet;
2. erase everything in the text editor;
3. change the title to "Set colour preview on edit";
4. paste this code in;
5. click File » Save.
*/

/*********
** Properties
*********/
/**
 * A regex pattern matching a valid CSS hex colour code.
 */
var colourPattern = /^#([0-9a-f]{3})([0-9a-f]{3})?$/i;


/*********
** Event handlers
*********/
/**
 * Sets the foreground or background color of a cell based on its value.
 * This assumes a valid CSS hexadecimal colour code like #FFF or #FFFFFF.
 */
function onEdit(e){
  // iterate over cell range  
  var range = e.range;
  var rowCount = range.getNumRows();
  var colCount = range.getNumColumns();
  for(var r = 1; r <= rowCount; r++) {
    for(var c = 1; c <= colCount; c++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(r, c);
      var value = cell.getValue();

      if(isValidHex(value)) {
        cell.setBackground(value);
        cell.setFontColor(getContrastYIQ(value));
      }
      else {
        cell.setBackground('white');
        cell.setFontColor('black');
      }
    }
  }
};


/*********
** Helpers
*********/
/**
 * Get whether a value is a valid hex colour code.
 */
function isValidHex(hex) {
  return colourPattern.test(hex);
};

/**
 * Change text color to white or black depending on YIQ contrast
 * https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/
 */
function getContrastYIQ(hexcolor){
    var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(1,2),16);
    var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(3,2),16);
    var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(5,2),16);
    var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
    return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a background or other format with a user drfined function. Also, your function doesnot reference a sheet. To run just a function you can use:

```
function setColorHEX() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell=ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell()
  cell.setBackground("#dc281e");
}
```

Notice 'ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell()'. This could be triggered by onEdit. However, it would be eaaier to use Conditional Formatting. Right click on the cell you want to set the background on. Choose 'Conditional Formatting'. Choose the condition you want. Under formatting style, click on fill color. On the popup click custom and you can enter your hex color.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an alteration on @ow3n's answer. My version uses batch and map operations to slim down both the amount of code and the execution time. According to [Best Practices | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), using batch operations speed up their example snippet 70 times.

For my application a fixed range was used. This could however be adapted to use a range given by the onEdit event. My version also colors cells with "their own" hex value, though I read the original question as asking how to color cells according to a value from another cell. I also didn't want to show the hex text, so I set the font color to the same color as the background.

My version:

```
var colorPattern = /^#([0-9a-f]{3})([0-9a-f]{3})?$/i;

function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var range1 = sheet.getRange('range1');
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('range2');
  
  colorRange(range1);
  colorRange(range2);
};

function colorRange(range) {
  var hexs = range.getValues();
  
  hexs = hexs.map( 
    (row) => 
      row.map(
        (value) => colorPattern.test(value) ? value : "white"
      )
  )
  
  range.setBackgroundColors(hexs);
  range.setFontColors(hexs);
}
```